# Can every d-regular graph be decomposed into at most d+1 matchings?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

If so, how would you prove it? This arose in a circuit context: a paper I was reading considers applying a two-bit gate to every pair of vertices that share an edge in some arbitrary d-regular graph, and claims that the gates can be applied in at most d+1 layers. Hence, I am also curious whether such a decomposition can be computed efficiently.

Comment: Consider a complete graph on $100$ vertices. It is regular of degree $99$. Can you decompose it into $100$ matchings? A matching can have one vertex?

Comment: @markvs The solution for the complete graph doesn't tell us how to do it in the general case.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: The question is: "Can every d-regular graph be decomposed into at least d+1 matchings?" The answer is "no". What else should be said?

Comment: @markvs The answer is "yes".

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I see that you prefer "yes". However, since **not every** $d$-regular graph can be decomposed into at least $d+1$ matchings, the answer to this particular question is "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Vizing's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem): every graph with maximum degree $\Delta$ has a proper edge coloring with $\Delta+1$ colors. In particular, every $d$-regular graph has a $(d+1)$-edge-coloring.

In a proper edge coloring, two edges that share an endpoint must have different colors. As a result, if you look at all the edges of a color, they must form a matching. We used $d+1$ colors, so we have decomposed the graph into $d+1$ matchings.

We can do this efficiently, but the proof of Vizing's theorem is not easy (it is the hardest proof I've ever covered in an introductory graph theory class), and accordingly the algorithms are not straightforward. See the [Misra & Gries edge-coloring algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misra_%26_Gries_edge_coloring_algorithm) on Wikipedia.

*Some* $d$-regular graphs admit a decomposition into only $d$ matchings, rather than $d+1$. (Of course, we can't do better, because all $d$ edges out of a vertex need to be in different matchings.) But in general, determining if we can shave off that one extra matching is NP-complete.